# Can I embed a markdown file in a markdown file with Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I am using Jekyll to generate a website.  Is it possible for a markdown file to include another markdown file?  This could be useful if, say, I want the same markdown text at the beginning of several pages.

Answer (score 5):

I've never used Jekyll but some Google searching [yields](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1303#issuecomment-21067548) a combination of `capture` and `markdownify`:

```
{% capture my_include %}{% include a_markdown_file.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ my_include | markdownify }}
```

You can substitute `my_include` with whatever name you want.

Sources:

- https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1303 (particularly relevant)
- http://ricostacruz.com/til/markdown-in-jekyll
- [Jekyll, include markdown with layout in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534299/jekyll-include-markdown-with-layout-in-html) (answer to *your* question is implied in this question's text)
- https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/

Comment: Thanks!  Will this syntax work in a markdown file, or just an html file?

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers No idea, sorry. I just took a quick stab in the dark to hopefully hold you over until you get a better answer. That jekyllrb.com article contains a sentence *"For example, if _posts/2014-09-03-my-file.markdown uses the include_relative tag ..."* which implies that at least one tag (include_relative) can be present in a markdown file. So you'll just have to try it. Btw, apparently [the filenames are important, too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28641029/616460).

Comment: Thanks, it works!  BTW, `markdownify` is unnecessary because the whole file is going to be converted from markdown to html later anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `include` works:

```
{% include markdown_file.md %}
```